# unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' for scatter plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scatter-plot, dtype

I am getting  `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'` error. so I cast the `df_subset` , `'Views'` to `int`,however, it is returning `object`

here is the script:

```
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, verbose=1, perplexity=20, n_iter=1000) 
tsne_results = tsne.fit_transform(logits_list)


df_subset = pd.DataFrame({'X':tsne_results[:,0], 'Y':tsne_results[:,1], 'Views':targets}) 
print(df_subset)
df_subset.astype({'Views': 'int'}).dtypes
print(df_subset.dtypes)

colors = {'A2CH':'red', 'A3CH':'green', 'A4CH_LV':'blue', 'A4CH_RV':'cyan', 'A5CH':'magneta', 'Apical_MV_LA_IAS':'yellow', 
          'PLAX_TV':'black', 'PLAX_full':'white', 'PLAX_valves':'orange', 'PSAX_AV':'purple', 'PSAX_LV':'dodgerblue', 'Subcostal_IVC':'lightgreen', 'Subcostal_heart':'darkcyan', 'Suprasternal':'grey'}

ax = sns.scatterplot(x= "X", y= "Y", hue='Views', legend = 'full',palette = colors, data=df_subset) 

plt.show()
```

here is a print of `df_subset and dtype`:

```
            X          Y Views
0   13.208739 -19.657906  [11]
1    7.932375 -31.547863   [6]
2   -3.896450 -23.075047   [9]
3  -11.836237 -12.138339   [9]
4   -8.077571  17.220371  [11]
5    9.463497  23.756912   [2]
6    8.354083 -47.790867  [10]
7   -2.848731  -0.220144   [9]
8   25.724466 -29.862696   [9]
9  -26.956612  -8.361418   [9]
10 -16.011475   2.309184   [7]
11  16.193329  -0.280985   [8]
12   5.060284  -9.906323   [9]
13  37.827713 -16.174528   [4]
14  -5.971475 -39.845860   [7]
15   6.608039   9.085782  [12]
16 -20.108206 -26.253906   [8]
17  32.851559   0.332044   [2]
18  23.818949  13.762548   [2]
19  23.625357 -12.107020   [3]
X        float32
Y        float32
Views     object
dtype: object
```

I assume I am getting the `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'` error because of object type? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe change to `'Views':targets.ravel()` in your creation of `df_subset`.

Comment: I agree with @QuangHoang or `df_subset.Views = df_subset.Views.str[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.astype()` returns a copy so it should work if you do

```
df_subset = df_subset.astype({'Views': int})
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jeyes Unterwegs. I am not getting that error, however, I cannot plot them. it thrown an error  "The palette dictionary is missing keys: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}", any idea?

Comment: it resolved by setting palette = sns.color_palette(n_colors=14)